# Multiple character lookup within square brackets with regex

Tags: regex, javascript, replace

I’m using regex in JavaScript for certain text replacements to convert legacy encoded text to unicode (it’s an indic language). Suppose I anywhere I find either of `a,b,c` followed by either of `x,y,z` followed by `e` I have to replace it so that e comes first. So I have code like this:

```
modified_substring = modified_substring.replace( /([abc])([xyz]*)e/g , "e$1$2" ) ;
```

Now let us say I want to modify this rule as `a` or `b` or `c` or `klm` followed by either of `x`,`y`,`z` followed by `e`. So what would the code be?

```
modified_substring = modified_substring.replace( /([abc]klm)([xyz]*)e/g , "e$1$2" ) ;
```

That apparently doesn’t work. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use alternation operator `|`.

```
modified_substring = modified_substring.replace( /([abc]|klm)([xyz]*)e/g , "e$1$2" ) ;
                                                        ^
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Avinash for sparing me the tedious work of digging into regex tutorials. That worked just fine. Btw just for info the 'klm's of the example are actually conjuncts in Indic which look like one letter but are treated as multiple in unicode.

Comment: if you have any further queries, please ask it as a new question. So that could be able to describe the actual problem with some examples.